# mule datamapper pojo to csv without any data

Tags: mule

I have a pojo class like below

```
public class Product {

    private String productName;
    private String quantity;
    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }
    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = "laptop";
    }
    public String getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }
    public void setQuantity(String quantity) {
        this.quantity = "25";
    }


}
```

**using datamapper converrt pojo  to csv**

```
 <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\temp" outputPattern="#[function:dateStamp]_product.csv" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
```

**it create file without any data like laptop,25**

Comment: Mule version? Full flow config? Are you sure `setProductName` and `setQuantity` are called?

Comment: //MEL
//START -> DO NOT REMOVE
output.productName = input.productName;
output.quantity = input.quantity;

Comment: This doesn't answer any of my questions. Did you check with a breakpoint or `System.out.println` that these setters are actually called?

Answer (score 1):

Datamapper will ignore the null values by default so, if you're not calling your setters, then the getters will return null, if you want to have "default" values you can do it the standard java way, either set it on the constructor or directly in the field declaration i.e

```
private String quantity = 25
```

Also for java in general, it is a bad practice to have public non-static non-final fields.